# UPPAAL: Selection from a predefined integer array

Tags: arrays, select, model-checking

So far I know how selections work in UPPAAL. You can use a statement like e.g. i : int[2,42] selecting all numbers between 2 and 42.

Now I have a network of n automata (each with a distinct id) and a 2 dimensional, preinitilized integer array n * k so every automaton has a k-long row of integers. How to make a selection from this array? Something like:

i : my_array[id]

So every automaton selects from its set of k predefined numbers?

Best, Pawel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. You do it this way:

```
i : int[1,k] // with k being the length of each row, as stated above
j = my_array[id][i]
```

Thus j will be assigned the numbers predefined in the array.